# How to override method of

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, oop, inheritance

There is a class alpha which has method -(void)doSomething. There is also a class beta which I've created and can modify as I need. Instance of alpha can only be created by calling [gamma createAlpha].

What I need is to make class beta to inherit alpha and override doSomething while I still have to create instances of alpha via calling [gamma createAlpha].

Is there any way to implement this?

I hope my question makes sense.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried making your gamma class an child of class alpha?

Comment: @Ares No because alpha and gamma are classes of framework/lib which I cannot change. Any other ideas?

Comment: @RaDo: then how do you create alpha object in gamma?

Comment: Instead of alpha,beta,gamma, write down your real requirment and post class code and add comments for your rquirment

Comment: @preetam What do you mean "how do you create alpha object in gamma"? I just call method createAlpha of gamma class and it returns new alpha object. It doesn't make sense to post real classes here because it will be much more confusing and will not help to address the real issue I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can use method swizzling. You will need to create category with following code:

```
@implementation alpha (newDoSomething)

// This is called when the category is being added
+ (void) load {
    Method method1 = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(doSomething));
    Method method2 = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(swizzleddoSomething));

    // this is what switches the two methods
    method_exchangeImplementations(method1, method2);
}

- (void)swizzleddoSomething
{
... your code
//You can call super implementation here with following line
//[self swizzleddoSomething];
}

@end
```

You will still have class alpha. It will be successfully created by [gamma createAlpha], but it will have your implementation of doSomething method.

Comment: Looks interesting but slightly hackish.. or not? Using this approach will my method be execute if alpha's doSomething will be called as delegate from another class?

Comment: Yes it will. It is not a hack it is a feature of Objective C runtime. But it should be used carefully. You can read about it here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/method_exchangeImplementations

Comment: Submitting an app to the store that performs method swizzling will result in said app being rejected. Just FYI.

Comment: I have already submitted few and had no problems. Method swizzling does not use any private API. Add link to prove your information, please.